# Filtering virtual machines on azure python sdk

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I've been trying to filter virtual machines while fetching it using the `ComputeClientManager` list function.
based on the documentation the list function 2nd argument is a string which represents a filter to filter the virtual machines by.

that is the function: `compute_client.virtual_machines.list(resource_group_name,filter_str)`

documentation page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_08_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-compute-v2022-08-01-operations-virtualmachinesoperations-list

unfortunately, I cannot understand what is the correct syntax of constructing this string as even the string example in the documentation doesn't seem to work.

I can't find a proper explanation to building those strings in Python and make it filter correctly. I want to filter based on tags, running machines, for example. any example for a proper string filter which works would be highly appreciated, or some kind of source with examples.

Thanks a lot!

i get this type of errors after trying to get a vm from the iterator returned from the list function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/paging.py", line 132, in __next__
    return next(self._page_iterator)
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/paging.py", line 76, in __next__
    self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/compute/v2022_11_01/operations/_virtual_machines_operations.py", line 2229, in get_next
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, error_format=ARMErrorFormat)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (ProviderError) Resource provider 'Microsoft.Compute' failed to return collection response for type 'virtualMachines'.
Code: ProviderError
Message: Resource provider 'Microsoft.Compute' failed to return collection response for type 'virtualMachines'.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Filtering virtual machines on Azure python SDK

To list the Azure virtual machine at the **`subscription level`** with a filter using Python you can use the below code:

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

subscription_id="Your-subscription-id"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

vms = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()

for vm in vms:
   if vm.tags is not None and 'Reason' in vm.tags: #This part is filter
      print(vm.name)
```

**Output:**

```
    sabodRHEL8.1Todel
    azurestoragetestvm
    lineofsight
    vmlinux
    ruk123
    vm326
```

[image]

To list the Azure virtual machine at the **`resource-group level`** with a filter using Python you can use the below code:

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

    subscription_id="Your-subscription-id"
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    resource_grp="Your-resourcegrp-name"
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

    vms = compute_client.virtual_machines.list(resource_group_name=resource_grp)

    for vm in vms:
          if vm.tags is not None and 'Reason' in vm.tags:
             print(vm.name)
```

**Output:**

```
  vm326
```

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks, those methods do filter the vms i want.
But, I was actually looking for a filter at the server level, in a way that does not require me to actually pull the entire vms list of the resource group.
From looking at the documentation it does explicitly say that the list() function can receive an additional filter str argument that is constructed as an OData string.
I just cannot seem to be able to deliver a string that either doesn't give an error or actually makes the function filter the vms.

Comment: This is the page in the documentation that shows this option:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_08_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-compute-v2022-08-01-operations-virtualmachinesoperations-list

Comment: @tomersonenfeld, I tried the documentation but it's not working for me as well, which I'm still trying to figure out. Meanwhile, can we consider the above solution as a workaround for your query?